# Estoy experimentando un problema cuando hago clic en un botón dentro de un WebView en React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

**Contexto:**

Tengo una aplicación hecha en React Native y esta tiene un componente que es un WebView que renderiza un mapa web. (Este mapa es una aplicación externa hecha con React, así que cuando hable del mapa, pensad en ello como la aplicación externa)

La app es ejecutada en una tablet Android.

He creado un botón dentro del visor mapa para centrar la vista en unas coordenadas (no es relevante la función).

**Problema:**

Cuando hago click en el botón, el WebView muestra este error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'RegExp')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'RegExp')
    at $o.i (http://192.168.0.15:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14554:132)
```

He intentado cambiar el timpo de evento y también buscar el origen en el código, pero ese bundle.js es código construido y ofuscado, imposible saber qué es cada cosa a simple vista.

**Código:**

Este es el código más relevante a mostrar, el WebView:

```
<WebView
ref={webviewRef}
onMessage={event => {
  if (
    event.nativeEvent.data &&
    event.nativeEvent.data === 'mapLoaded'
  ) {
    setmapLoaded(true);
  }
}}
source={{
  uri: 'http://192.168.0.15:3000/',
}}
onError={(error)=>{console.log(error)}}
/>
```

Y el error:

```
$o.prototype.i = function (a) {
var b = a.type,
  c = vo(this.f);
c = {
  x: a.pageX - c.x,
  y: a.pageY - c.y
};
var d;
(d = this.a.a[0] || null) || (d = new xo(c.x, c.y, 1, "mouse"), this.a.push(d));
this.b.push(d);
yo(d, c.x, c.y);
/^mouse(?:move|over|out)$/.test(b) ? Ko(this, "pointermove", a) : (/^mouse(down|up)$/.test(b) && (c = a.which - 1, "up" === wo.RegExp.$1 ? Bo(d, c) : zo(d, c)), Ko(this, b.replace("mouse", "pointer"), a));
this.b.clear();
};
```